# When does a glue node have type `xspaceskip` in LuaTeX?

Tags: spacing, luatex, glue

I am using TeX Live 2017, and the [current luatex documentation of glue nodes](http://www.luatex.org/svn/tags/1.0.3/manual/luatex.pdf#page=107) says that the `subtype` field of a glue node has the following possible values:

> 0 = userskip, 1 = lineskip, 2 = baselineskip, 3 = parskip, 4 = abovedisplayskip,
>   5 = belowdisplayskip, 6 = abovedisplayshortskip, 7 = belowdisplayshortskip,
>   8 = leftskip, 9 = rightskip, 10 = topskip, 11
>   = splittopskip, 12 = tabskip, 13 = spaceskip, 14 = xspaceskip, 15
>   = parfillskip, 16 = mathskip, 17 = thinmuskip, 18 = medmuskip, 19 =
>   thickmuskip, 98 = conditionalmathskip, 99 = muglue, 100 = leaders,
>   101 = cleaders, 102 = xleaders, 103 = gleaders

I was trying to learn about LuaTeX and wrote the following simple code to just spew out some informative output about each paragraph:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile("parinfo.lua")}
\begin{document}

Word1, word2 office. Word3. End.
\end{document}
```

where `parinfo.lua` is:

```lua
function traverse_paragraph(head)
   while head do
      print(string.format('In paragraph: %s %s', node.type(head.id), debugstr_node(head)))
      head = head.next
   end
  return true
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback('pre_linebreak_filter', traverse_paragraph, 'Info for debugging')

function debugstr_node(n)
   if node.type(n.id) == "glue" then
      return debugstr_glue(n)
   elseif node.type(n.id) == "glyph" then
      return n.char < 128 and string.char(n.char) or string.format('[char %s]', n.char)
   elseif node.type(n.id) == "kern" then
      return string.format('%s', n.kern)
   elseif node.type(n.id) == "penalty" then
      return string.format('%s', n.penalty)
   else
      return ''
   end
end

function debugstr_glue(n)
   if n.subtype == 13 then
      subtype = 'spaceskip'
   elseif n.subtype == 14 then
      subtype = 'xspaceskip'
   elseif n.subtype == 15 then
      subtype = 'parfillskip'
   else
      subtype = '' .. n.subtype
   end
   return string.format('<%s: %s plus %s(%s) minus %s(%s)', subtype, n.width, n.stretch, n.stretch_order, n.shrink, n.shrink_order)
end
```

So when the `.tex` file is compiled with `lualatex`, we get output like:

```
In paragraph: local_par 
In paragraph: hlist 
In paragraph: glyph W
In paragraph: kern -54395
In paragraph: glyph o
In paragraph: glyph r
In paragraph: glyph d
In paragraph: glyph 1
In paragraph: glyph ,
In paragraph: glue <spaceskip: 218235 plus 136396(0) minus 58196(0)
In paragraph: glyph w
In paragraph: kern -18350
In paragraph: glyph o
In paragraph: glyph r
In paragraph: glyph d
In paragraph: glyph 2
In paragraph: glue <spaceskip: 218235 plus 109117(0) minus 72745(0)
In paragraph: glyph o
In paragraph: glyph [char 64259]
In paragraph: glyph c
In paragraph: glyph e
In paragraph: glyph .
In paragraph: glue <spaceskip: 290980 plus 327351(0) minus 24248(0)
In paragraph: glyph W
In paragraph: kern -54395
In paragraph: glyph o
In paragraph: glyph r
In paragraph: glyph d
In paragraph: glyph 3
In paragraph: glyph .
In paragraph: glue <spaceskip: 290980 plus 327351(0) minus 24248(0)
In paragraph: glyph E
In paragraph: glyph n
In paragraph: glyph d
In paragraph: glyph .
In paragraph: penalty 10000
In paragraph: glue <parfillskip: 0 plus 65536(2) minus 0(0)
```

Note that the glue after the comma (which has larger stretch) and that after the `.` (which has larger width and larger stretch) are still both shown as having subtype `spaceskip`, rather than `xspaceskip`. (The glue at the end of the paragraph has subtype `parfillskip`, as expected.)

Is this expected? When would we see glue having type `xspaceskip`? And is there an alternative way in the pre_linebreak filter of detecting the larger glue that follows punctuation or end-of-sentence (with `\nonfrenchspacing`), other than keeping track of say recently seen interword glue and comparing for differences?

I don't fully understand the workings of these even for non-LuaTeX so I may just be confused :-) In case it matters, `luatex --version` says

> This is LuaTeX, Version 1.0.4 (TeX Live 2017)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

when you set `\xspaceskip`

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{dofile("parinfo.lua")}
\setlength\xspaceskip{10pt}
\begin{document}

Word1, word2 office. Word3. End.
\end{document}
```

---

```
In paragraph: glyph 3
In paragraph: glyph .
In paragraph: glue <xspaceskip: 655360 plus 0(0) minus 0(0)
In paragraph: glyph E
```